# Просит заполнить все формы, вместо одной во flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Делаю страницу-квест. Находишь ответ по ссылке, вбиваешь в форму, а затем то, что уже отгадано висит надписью, а там где еще нет - висит `input`. Но когда я нажимаю отправить, то он просит заполнить все формы сразу. Как это поправить? Кусок кода:

```
@app.route('/current/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def current():
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['1'] == 'Dear':
        alphabet.update({'e':True})
    if request.form['2'] == 'Anna':
        alphabet.update({'i': True})
    if request.form['3'] == 'i':
        alphabet.update({'l': True})
    if request.form['4'] == 'must':
        alphabet.update({'o': True})
    if request.form['5'] == 'tell':
        alphabet.update({'u': True})
    if request.form['6'] == 'you':
        alphabet.update({'v': True})
    if request.form['7'] == 'that':
        alphabet.update({'y': True})
    tmp = 0
    for i in alphabet:
        if alphabet[i] == True:
            tmp += 1
    if tmp == 7:
        return render_template('page.html')
return render_template('current.html', alphabet=alphabet)
```

страница с jinja:

```
<div>
    <form action="{{ url_for('the__coolest_quest') }}" method="post">
            {% if alphabet['e'] == True %}
                <div>
                    <label>Ключевое слово <strong>Dear</strong> разгадано</label>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div>
                    <label>Ключевое слово - обращение(<a href=""></a>)</label>
                    <input type="text" name="1" required>
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
    </form>
</div>
```

alphabet:

```
просто словарь str:bool
```

Таких условий в форме 7 штук, не стал все копировать, они аналогичные. Так вот когда я нажимаю отправить на любой из input, то браузер просит заполнить все остальные input'ы обязательно. Как это поправить?

Comment: Посмотрите что слово required означает. В сторону: для удобства пользователя, не стоит всю страницу перегружать для каждого ввода (асинхронные запросы в javascript можно делать и обновлять части страницы, [пример](https://goo.gl/PDYBer)) и даже submit не обязательно требовать нажимать. `alphabet.update({'e':True})` можно как `alphabet['e'] = True` записать.`if alphabet[i] == True` следует как `if alphabet[i]` писать.

Comment: здесь вероятно достаточно `if all(request.form[str(i)] == value for i, value in enumerate("Dear Anna i must tell you that".split(), start=1)): return render_template('page.html')`

Comment: @jfs гениально, оформи как ответ, это рили облегчает код)

Comment: all(..) фрагмент не должен изменить поведения кода в вопросе и поэтому не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @jfs насчет required в input все правильно